# Hide error message span with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do an email validation through a javasript function.

```js
function checkEmail() {
  email_address = $("#email");

  email_regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i;
  if (!email_regex.test(email_address.val())) {
    if (email_address != '') {

      $("#emailerror").html("invalid email");
      $("#emailerror").show();
    }

  } else {
    $("#emailerror").html("");
    $("#emailerror").hide();

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="" class="form-control" id="email" onBlur="checkEmail()">
<span id="emailerror"></span>
```

The problem is when I enter an invalid email it displays the "invalid email" message, but when I retype a valid email or an empty one, it doesn't hide the "invalid email" message in the error span! Even when I put error.hide() and error.html("").
Please help and thanks .

Comment: when is this function called ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this; typing a proper email and pressing tab hides the error message just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/d72v3azf/

Comment: _“but when i retype a valid email or an empty one it dosen't hide”_ - but you did “leave” the field first, so that the `blur` event fires in the first place, yes? Btw., `if (email_address!='')` - that is never going to be false, because `email_address` is the jQuery object here, you are not testing the field _value_ here.

Comment: @CBroe yes i when i type an invalid email and it shows the error message then i type a valid email and i leave the email input it still showing the same message

Comment: @ChrisG thanks you solved the problem , but please can i know what you added to it and thanks again :)

Comment: _“then i type a valid email and i leave the email input it still showing the same message”_ - not even your example here is able to reproduce that behavior for me. Wrong email, shows error - I type a correct email, leave the field, and the error message disappears.

Comment: And your regular expression is of course the usual bad stuff people come up with (or find somewhere) when trying to “validate emails” - for example TLDs with more than 4 characters have existed for quite some time now.

Comment: @BechirGharsallah I didn't change anything at all, otherwise I'd have told you what to fix instead of "I cannot reproduce this"

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working. See snippet. Some other code is probably interfering with it.

```js
function checkEmail(){
  email_address = $("#email");

  email_regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i;
  if(!email_regex.test(email_address.val())) {
    if (email_address!='') {
      $("#emailerror").html("invalid email");
      $("#emailerror").show();
    }
  }
  else{
    $("#emailerror").html("");
    $("#emailerror").hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="" class="form-control" id="email" onBlur="checkEmail()">
<span id="emailerror"></span>
```

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use an email input ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email

They are compatible with every browser since IE 10

```html
<input id="emailAddress" type="email" title="Please provide a valid email address">
```

the email pattern is already inside of it and you can even add your own pattern on top of it with the [`pattern` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern)

---

If you really want to show a text you can do someting like this :

```css
#emailAddress:invalid ~ div::before {
  content: "Your email is invalid"
}
```

```html
<input id="emailAddress" type="email" title="Please provide a valid email address">
<div></div>
```

which is compatible for all browsers since IE 10 too